# ServiceStack/Razor - how to use external MVC control (DevExpress)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, devexpress, servicestack

As a base, I'm using this tutorial: http://www.ienablemuch.com/2012/12/self-hosting-servicestack-serving.html

So, my project works fine, I have some cshtmls, they are compiling and displaying correctly. But I need some more complex functionality and I don't want to write this from scratch. Instead, I want to use devexpress mvc controls and this is where my problem begins.

There is devexpress mvc sample, it's very simple with standard Microsoft MVC: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E3326.aspx

For testing/learning purposes, I want to to use the same control and get the same effect in my selfhosting ServiceStack project, created as mentioned above.Unfortunatelly, I don't even know where to start, since my project structure is slightly (or even more slightly) different.

Can you look at that devexpress sample and provide some tips for me what should I do to embed external devexpress control in my project?

Comment: Why don't you contact DevExpress support directly?

Comment: They don't want to ansewer questions from trial users, their support is available for users with full licence.

Answer (score 1):

A few things I would look into.

- Does a simple control compile within ServiceStack.Razor?
- Does can you bind a simple control to a Model.

Quickly looking at the code this seems like it could cause issues:

- GridViewPartial.cs

  - settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Home", Action = "GridViewPartial" }; - My question would be how to create the ServiceStack url and return the necessary 'partial/html' response.

Comment: Yes, and because of these issues I don't know how to start. Any help is highly appreciated.